# how to get max blocks in thrust in cuda 5.5

Tags: cuda, thrust

The Thrust function below can get the maximum blocks of for a CUDA launch CUDA 5.0, which is used by Sparse Matrix Vector multiplication(SpMV) in CUSP, and it is a technique for setting up execution for persistent threads. The first line is the header file.

```
#include <thrust/detail/backend/cuda/arch.h>

thrust::detail::backend::cuda::arch::max_active_blocks(kernel<float,int,VECTORS_PER_BLOCK,TH    READS_PER_VECTOR>,THREADS_PER_BLOCK,(size_t)0)
```

But the function is not supported by CUDA 5.5. Was this technique not supported by CUDA 5.5, or should I use some other function instead?

Answer (score 2):

There was never any supported way to perform this computation in any version of Thrust. Headers inside `thrust/detail` and identifiers inside a `detail` namespace are part of Thrust's implementation -- they are not public features. Using them will break your code.

That said, there's some standalone code implementing the occupancy calculator in this repository:

https://github.com/jaredhoberock/cuda_launch_config

Comment: the number of threads in the block of original SpMV is 128, and a row is done by one warp, the implement of occupancy calculator of [cuda_launch_config](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/cuda_launch_config) is the max threads, and it may be difficult to control. So the best way is to used the API of original persist thread, and it will avoid to modify the original code of SpMV