# What API replaced thrust::detail::device::cuda::arch::max_active_blocks in newer thrust version?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, thrust

I am tring to compile [voxelpipe](https://code.google.com/p/voxelpipe/) and get the following error:

```
error : name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name
```

on line:

```
const int32 BLOCK_SIZE = 512;
dim3 dim_block = dim3( BLOCK_SIZE, 1, 1 );
dim3 dim_grid  = dim3( thrust::detail::device::cuda::arch::max_active_blocks(compute_tile_ranges<BLOCK_SIZE,tile_id_type>, BLOCK_SIZE, 0), 1, 1 );
```

I looked up the thrust source code and found it seems this function exists no more in newer versions of thrust, but I do not know how to modify the source code to achieve the same calculation in newer versions of thrust.

I am using CUDA 7.0, VS 2013.

-------- edited on 2015-7-11 22:36:50-----------
Yeah, now I know we've got an [useful answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726720/how-to-get-max-blocks-in-thrust-in-cuda-5-5), and I am going to use the [cuda launch config code](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/cuda_launch_config) in my modification of  voxelpipe, but I really need to know what exactly what "max_active_blocks" did before I set off.
The [cuda launch config code](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/cuda_launch_config) gives the best value of num_threads, while the above voxelpipe code used a fixed BLOCK_SIZE = 512, then a calculation is done to give a proper grid size, which is very strange.
If we got a set of data to compute in kernel, shouldn't the value of BLOCK_SIZE * grid_size be fixed? Why the code in voxelpipe is adjusting gridsize while leaving BLOCK_SIZE fixed?

Comment: This could help you: https://github.com/jaredhoberock/cuda_launch_config

Comment: This was never a supported feature of thrust and shouldn't have been used. The linked github code is a suitable replacement

Comment: There are [officially-supported APIs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OCCUPANCY.html#group__CUDART__OCCUPANCY) for computing occupancy-related stuff now.